# In kubernetes how to access a service using dns names?

Tags: kubernetes

How do i provide a service with a dns name in the deployment file so that i can access that service from some other service from the same cluster?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment

metadata:
  name: db
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: db
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: db
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: db
        image: mysql:5.7.29
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: "root"
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/log/mysql/
          name: mysql
      volumes:
      - name: mysql
        hostPath:
          path: "/home/sandeep/logs/mysql/"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: database
  labels:
    app: db
spec:
  selector:
    app: db
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: database
    port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
```

This is mysql deployment file so how can i provide this service with a dns name? In which do i need to make change?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you created the database service in `default` namespace you can access mysql via `database.default.svc.cluster.local` from any namespace and via `database.svc.cluster.local` from the same namespace.

Comment: im able to do a ping but its showing 100% packet loss.                                                  
 PING 10.152.183.111 (10.152.183.111): 56 data bytes
36 bytes from 172.25.8.164: Time to live exceeded

Comment: CoreDNS and kube proxy pods are running in kube-system namespace?

Comment: coreDNS is running but kube-proxy is not how to i enable that?

Comment: it should run by kubernetes...what is the IP of the pod ? provide output of kubectl describe svc database. are you trying to ping from another pod?

Comment: ```Name:              database
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app=db
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=db
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.152.183.54
Port:              database  3306/TCP
TargetPort:        3306/TCP
Endpoints:         <none>
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```   Yes im trying to ping from another pod.

Comment: is the service and pods in the same namespace ? Are the pods running? the endpoints should have Pod IPs...https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#does-the-service-have-any-endpoints

Comment: ```NAME                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP           NODE     NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
db-664ccb67f-8d4q2             1/1     Running   0          8m7s   10.1.52.55   vostro   <none>           <none>
vusmartmaps-66d4c789d8-khkrq   1/1     Running   0          8m7s   10.1.52.54   vostro   <none>           <none>``` Yeah both the service are running .

Answer (score 2):

The DNS is based on the service name and namespace. In most cases you just use the service name but the full name would be database.default.svc.cluster.local or similar depending on your domain config.

Comment: im able to do a ping but its showing 100% packet loss.                                               
```PING 10.152.183.111 (10.152.183.111): 56 data bytes 36 bytes from 172.25.8.164: Time to live exceeded  ```

Comment: They aren't real hosts, the is nothing to respond to pings. Services are built out of magic iptables rules.